# Why didn't they recreate the Wormhole in Pathfinder Episode

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek Voyager, S6E10, Pathfinder, Lieutenant Barclay is able to create a micro-wormhole in order communicate with Voyager.

> Meanwhile, the real Voyager, far in the Delta Quadrant, detects the micro-wormhole and a communication signal which Seven of Nine disbelievingly identifies as Federation in origin on a Starfleet Emergency Channel. The crew attempts to clear up the signal while, back on Earth, the jubilant officers and Barclay assist.
>
> For a few seconds, the team on Earth clear up the return signal, two-way communication is established for 86 seconds before the micro-wormhole collapses. A few words are exchanged and data from Voyager's logs, crew reports, and navigational records are transmitted to Earth.
>
> Barclay sends "data on some new hyper-subspace technology", along with recommended modifications to the ship's communications system, so that Voyager's crew will be able to keep regular contact with home. In the final seconds, the crew hear some moving words from Admiral Paris ending with, "I want you all to know we're doing everything we can to bring you home."

So, the Wormhole collapses after a few seconds / minutes. Why didn't they just "reopen" it, e.g. be placing the array next to the needed anomaly in order to be able to have it open permanently (or at least such that they can contact Voyager on a regular basis)?

Comment: It looks like you've taken the quote from Wikipedia. Please provide attribution for words that are not your own. You can edit it into your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Creating the microwormhole relies on a rare stellar object (an "itinerant pulsar") passing within a microscopic fraction of a light year of a specific Federation communications array.

> **BARCLAY:** *I've been going over the interstellar phenomena forecasts from Deep Space Nine. They are predicting er, a class B itinerant pulsar will pass within four billion kilometers of the MIDAS array in three days.*
>
> **HARKINS:** *You think the pulsar might damage the array?*
>
> **BARCLAY:** *No, no. The shields will hold. Actually I was thinking, we could use the pulsar to our own advantage*

Theoretically, I suppose they could build another gigantic array that just happens to be in the path of one of these pulsars, but it would take vast amounts of time, effort and energy to achieve another data burst.

Comment: So, they could "tow" the communications array along the pulsar in order have the ability to communicate frequently with Voyager? Or what prevents them from doing this?

Comment: @Shade - Presumably the same thing that stops them moving DS9. It's enormous and presumably extremely fragile. Since the pulsar is only in range of the array for a few seconds, it must also be moving at relativistic sublight speeds. Imagine trying to drag an oil platform behind a fleet of speedboats all moving along at top speed

Comment: @Valorum but there's no drag in space

Comment: @AzorAhai — The parts of the array all have inertia, which works sort of like atmospheric drag. If the towing force isn't applied evenly to all parts of the array — including internal components — or if the array's inertial dampers fail or even waver a bit, the array could be damaged.

Comment: @AzorAhai - That's not quite true; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/d/d9/Quark_as_Lumba.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100106000630&path-prefix=en

Comment: Actually, for Voyager to build another MIDAS array wouldn't really require much effort or time. The crew could easily use transporters and replicators (which could be powered in an uninhabited star system) that would be automated by the computer to create the whole array in a very short time frame.

Next step would be to find a suitable pulsar and to tow the array within 4 billion km of it (which can be achieved by projecting a subspace field around the station that would lower its mass and adjust it to compensate for Voyager's walp velocity).

Comment: Another option is that Voyager crew could create their own Wormhole. By the time the MIDAS array was constructed and Barclay opened a microwormhole, Ds9 already demonstrated in one of its episodes that Starfleet CAN create its own artificial wormholes using a properly modified torpedo.
It wasn't safe for ships to pass through, however, they probably would have known by Voyager Season 6 how to use sensors to scan and send messages through it

Comment: @Deks - All of the things you're describing would take years to accomplish. By the time this array was finished (assuming it wasn't taken away from them by the Borg or whoever), they would have run out of fuel for their replicators and died.

Comment: No it wouldn't. Trek and various episodes from TNG, DS9 and VOY demonstrated that the crews and ships can harvest resources on the go and use them as opposed to drain their own systems.
Replicators can be powered by other energy sources like solar, etc. and replication doesn't take a long time to complete. In fact, it takes less than 5 seconds... and transporters were shown to be able to transport shuttles. The MIDAS ARRAY is not excessively huge. It wouldn't take nearly as much time or resources you think.

Automation can construct matter thousands of times faster.

Comment: @Deks - You're engaged in fanfic. The Voyager barely has sufficient resources to keep itself on the road (and on several occasions literally runs out of fuel), let alone engage in grand building projects. It's like asking someone driving a Morris Minor from Lands End to John O'Groats with £20 in their wallet to *stop off and build a small castle.*

Comment: Not really.
Voyager stopped on a regular basis in other star systems to replenish its own resources for example, or to trade with other species for anti-matter, etc.

I'm thinking Voyager just didn't want to stay in a given star system for longer they needed to, seeing how chances were they would encounter other star systems along the road, or technologically developed races that could trade anti-matter for example directly (which would be more efficient than staying in a star system for weeks engaging in production - which they might have considered if no other option presented itself).